# Would bow shooting work different in an O'Neill cylinder?

Tags: science-based, weapons, gravity, space-constructs

The setting takes place in an Island 3 O'Neill cylinder. All type of bows included. I wonder if there are things to take into consideration when describing how a person would target and shoot, as well how the arrow flies, compared to bow shooting on earth.

Also, what if a skilled person with a compound bow would shoot straight up; could it technically hit the other side (the side above)? Or would the difference of gravity in the centre of the cylinder prevent such.

**Edit:** Please excuse the duplicate, these questions did not show up on my search. I understand now that the direction in which one would shoot will be essential; spinwards or antispinwards, and the range for additional drop or reductional drop is equal in length (either x meters "more" or "less" than on earth). One can drop something to determine the direction one stands in.

I would appreciate an answer to, what if one would shoot "to the side" (= not spin- or antispinwards)? Is my guess correct that the drop rate is +/- 0 and one would hit the intended target?

Comment: I asked this question not too long ago https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/150259/30492

Comment: Good question, I've closed it as a duplicate since I think it's already answered there but anything that isn't covered feel free to ask as a follow on question.

Comment: Also related: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/156146/62341

Comment: (now I'm strongly feeling the need to work out whether it is possible to shoot yourself with a bow in a rotating habitat, and what the parameters of such a habitat would have to be...)

Comment: it is absolutely possible, you just shoot up at the rotational velocity / pi